# $(a\cdot X+b\cdot Y)\mathbin{\%}P=0$, looking for $a$ and $b$ if they exist

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We are given three numbers $X,Y,P$.

$$(aX+bY)\mathbin{\%} P=0$$
Is there any method (some mathematical rule) to check if there exist two positive numbers $a$ and $b$ which satisfy the above equation ?

Comment: If $P\ne 0$, then $a=b=|P|$ works trivially.  Perhaps you should clarify your question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm may help